# Sorting without ORDER BY

Tags: sql, sorting, sql-order-by

It sounds retarded but can it be possible?

I have `EMPLOYEE_ID` and `DEPARTMENT_ID` and I have to sort it according to the `DEPARTMENT_ID` without using `ORDER BY`.

It should not present anywhere in the query i.e in `USING` clause or in SUB-QUERY or in SELECT statement or in anywhere.

Is it possible?

Comment: No. `ORDER BY` is the *one* place where you can specify *what* ordering guarantees you want the system to provide. The system is free to return results in any order that is convenient, *provided* it complies with the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. but you must be a very good with logic, there is bubble sort, divide and sort etc. logic available

Comment: If you want a specific order, do `ORDER BY`. (Even if you get the wanted order without it, it may change later, due to changed optimization etc.)

Comment: This is impossible. The ***only*** way to sort results is to use an `order by` (really: that's the **only** way)

Comment: Not unless you're [Chuck Norris.](http://www.chucknorrisfacts.com/all-chuck-norris-facts)

Comment: I dunno what are you trying to do but you could try with group by (sort by groups and in this case it'd DEPARTMEND_ID.

Comment: I was not trying to  do anything. I was just curious. @Jessica,@Madhivanan

Comment: @Jessica That should be the answer (for some RDBMS). + [Does “group by” automatically guarantee “order by”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28149876/does-group-by-automatically-guarantee-order-by)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few approaches that can work depending on particular RDBMS and none of them is to be used in production environment, but just for fun:

1. Use XML output and apply server-side XSLT transformation (through CLR for instance) with `<xsl:sort>`.
2. Use stored procedure to produce sorted list in one text return value.
3. Write own SQL proxy client replacing `-- HIDDEN MESSAGE` with `ORDER BY`. (I admit, this is not exactly SQL solution).
4. Create an Indexed (Materialized) View on the table sorted by `DEPARTMENT_ID` that would be solely used by this query. **Not guaranteed to work every single time**.
5. Create temporary table with all possible IDs in incremental order, left join source table on `DEPARTMENT_ID` and use hints to prevent optimizer from reordering joins. **Not guaranteed to work every single time**.

**Upd** 6.  When there are fewer rows to sort then the RDBMS supported CTE recursion depth:

```
With Example (EMPLOYEE_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID) As (
        Select 4, 2 Union All
        Select 5, 2 Union All
        Select 6, 3 Union All
        Select 7, 3 Union All
        Select 2, 1 Union All
        Select 3, 1 Union All
        Select 1, 1
    ),
    Stringified (ID) AS (
        Select
            RIGHT('0000000000' + CAST(DEPARTMENT_ID AS NVARCHAR(10)), 10) +
            RIGHT('0000000000' + CAST(EMPLOYEE_ID AS NVARCHAR(10)), 10)
        From Example
    ),
    Sorted (PREV_EMPLOYEE_ID, PREV_DEPARTMENT_ID,
            NEXT_EMPLOYEE_ID, NEXT_DEPARTMENT_ID) As (
        Select
            CAST(Right(ex1.ID, 10) AS INT),
            CAST(Left(ex1.ID, 10) AS INT),
            CAST(Right(Min(ex2.ID),10) AS INT),
            CAST(Left(Min(ex2.ID),10) AS INT)
        From Stringified ex1
        Inner Join Stringified ex2 On ex1.ID < ex2.ID
        Group By ex1.ID
    ),
    RecursiveCTE (EMPLOYEE_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID) AS (
        Select
            CAST(Right(Min(ID),10) AS INT),
            CAST(Left(Min(ID),10) AS INT)
        From Stringified
        Union All
        Select NEXT_EMPLOYEE_ID, NEXT_DEPARTMENT_ID
        From Sorted
        Inner Join RecursiveCTE
             ON RecursiveCTE.EMPLOYEE_ID = Sorted.PREV_EMPLOYEE_ID
            AND RecursiveCTE.DEPARTMENT_ID = Sorted.PREV_DEPARTMENT_ID
    )
Select *
From RecursiveCTE
```

**Upd** 7. Many RDBMS engines would sort result when applying `GROUP BY`, `UNION`, `EXCEPT`, `INTERSECT` or just `DISTINCT` especially if they are single-threaded or forced not to use parallelism with a hint. **Not guaranteed to work every single time**.

Answer (score 1):

That could be possible if you would create a index on your table where first(or only) key is `DEPARTMENT_ID` and you would force your query engine to use this index. This should be a plain `SELECT` statement as well.

But even then, it won't guarantee correct sort order.

Comment: Even if you force a particular index to be used, it's still not guaranteed. E.g. In some circumstances, SQL Server will piggy-back one query's data access off of the back of another, already running query. So, it *could* pick up on an index scan already in progress, use that for some results, and then do a partial scan of the start of that index to complete its full scan. It's crazy what SQL systems *can* do because of the freedom that the language is designed to allow.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever. Postgres, Oracle and DB2 will also re-use running (table) scans in the same way.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I agree. I just told that it *could* be theoretically possible, that's it. Other than that, `ORDER BY` is only correct way to do this.

Comment: How would you "force your query engine" to use this index? Even if you did, the data might be already in cache and the index could be untouched.

Comment: @cliffordheath That's possible in SQL Server. [Please read this link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/02/07/sql-server-introduction-to-force-index-query-hints-index-hint/)

Comment: A query "hint" does not force the optimiser to use that index. It's a *hint*. If the data is already cached, it might use *no* index.

Answer (score 0):

May be this link would help you

[sort results without use of order by clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357134/sort-results-without-use-of-order-by-clause?rq=1)

This is what the link says

> You cannot, at least not reliably.
>
> Some SQL implementations may well return rows in the order of their
>   primary keys or clustered indexes, but SQL itself is a relational
>   algebra that returns arbitrarily ordered sets unless specifically told
>   otherwise.
>
> There's a good chance that the order in which rows are returned may
>   well depend on the insertion and deletion activity since the table was
>   created.

Comment: Should have been a comment, not an answer.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10959609)

Comment: @DavidPilkington Edited the answer now. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You could make your query without ORDER BY, put every row into a multidimensional array and after that sorting your array. It can be done in several languages.

In PHP it would be something like this:

```
$result = [];
// In $result you put every row from your SELECT

$aSortField = [];

    foreach ($result as $key => $row)   
        {
        $aSortField [$key] = $row['theNameOfYourSortColumn'];
        }

    array_multisort($aLocal, SORT_ASC, $result);    // This makes the "order by" job
```

Comment: That is the antithesis of the requested answer.

Comment: I can see that's one way of solving it, although my impression was that the need was to do it in SQL rather than elsewhere, and the OP didn't mention PHP.